# How to call a method and show data with async? It does nothing when I try to

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method where I am reading some details on a person. Something like a master detail.
That action is invoked inside a popover. I need to make the call a method asynchronously.
When I call the method with the ajax parameter async:true,it fails. It does nothing,it does not show a popover and it does not throw any exceptions in the console.
This is my code:
C#

```
public async Task<ActionResult> PersonDetails(int id)
    {
        var model =  await _context.Person.Where(e => e.Person == id && e.Age > 5).ToListAsync();
        return View(model);
    }
```

ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Home/PersonDetails/" + id,
            method: "post",
            async: true,

            //data: { id: id },
            success: function (data) {
                set_data = data;
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                console.log(jqXHR.statusText + textStatus + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

When there are no async,Task and await in controller and when async is set to false is works.Also if I keep the async Task and await on controller and set ajax async to false,it works.
How to fix this?

Comment: If you debug your controller does it hit the controller and run all the code?

Comment: you are using `'post'` in your ajax method, but I do not see `[HttpPost]` attribute above your C# controller method, unless you omitted from the example.

Comment: I have added httpost, it acts the same.
When I debug nothing happens.Like I never clicked on a button.

Comment: If your controller action is not hit when you debug, check your routes if its correctly configured.

Comment: Open your browser network tab and check the status for this particular request...

Comment: Make sure you setup routing path correctly

Comment: my routes are fine,because if I put async:false it all works well

Comment: It's an HTTP request. The technology implementing the client or the sever has no effect in how the HTTP protocol works. Have you checked what the browser is sending to the server and what's being returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my code logic. I have set the data before calling the method that calls ajax.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$.ajax()` calls are asynchronous by nature and defaults to true, so you don't need add `async: true`
2. Use `data: { id: id }`, and remove `+ id` from `url:`
3. Replace `async Task<ActionResult>` with `JsonResult` (required `using System.Web.Mvc`)
4. Add `[HttpPost]` above `public JsonResult PersonDetails(int id) { ... }`
5. Use `var model = _context.Person.Where(e => e.Person == id && e.Age > 5).ToList();`
6. Return `return Json(model);` not return View
7. Done ! You can `console.log(data);` in the $.ajax.success function to see the return data.

Comment: But if I don't specify the async Task and use await in the c# backend, how is that asynchronous reading  then?